# How to make a table of items in resume?

Tags: tables, itemize, multicol, cv

Hi I am writing my resume in Latex. In "Professional service" section, I wish to list journals I refereed papers to. And I wish to do something like the following template.

[image]

It seems that the names of journals are put in a table and as items. Could any one let me know how to achieve this? Thanks.

**Update:**

Another minor issue is that in the picture, we see the line "refereed articles for ..." and the line right below has a large blank space. Is there a way to remove that? Obviously we wish to save space in a resume.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the first thing to realize is that isn't a table -- it's a two-column list :) after that, it's pretty easy to find `multicol` from a google search.

Comment: It can be done with `tabularx` or with `tasks` or with `shortlst`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a two-column list, not a table. Use `multicol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\section{Professional Service}
Refereed articles for the following journals:
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item The Journal of the American Statistical Association
  \item Genetic Epidemiology
  \item The American Statistician
  \item Journal of Machine Learning Research
  \item PLoS ONE
  \item Statistics in Medicine
  \item Frontiers in Genetics 
  \item Journal of Multivariate Analysis
  \item Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics
  \item Journal of Translated Medicine
  \item Annals of Statistics
  \item Statistical Papers
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks. How can i remove the large blank space between the line "Refereed articles for ..." and the line right below? I wish to save space for resume.

Comment: Check out the `enumitem` package. There are plenty of questions on this site that deal with vertical space when just dealing with `itemize` et al. Since this is wrapped in `multicols`, you should use the optional argument to that environment: `\begin{multicols}{2}[Refereed articles for the following journals:]`. If *all else fails*, you can use `\vspace`.